# Creating user profile using google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, clevertap

Is there any way to create user profile using google analytics(gtag.js) like we do in cleverTap using clevertap.profile.push ?

Answer (score 0):

While it might be technically possible via clever use of custom dimensions, it would violate Google's [terms of service](https://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html).

> You will not and will not assist or permit any third party to, pass information to Google that Google could use or recognize as
>   personally identifiable information.

Basically the only personally identifiable data you are allowed to
store is a (at least) SHA256 hash of an email address (to use e.g. as
user id. At least under the rules of the GDPR this would count as
PII).

So the question is moot. Even if you could, you mustn't.